# Logstash XPATH Querying XML element value based on a CSV field Value

Tags: xml, csv, xpath, logstash

I have a CSV file to parse using logstash. i am able to get each of the rows to elastic search from CSV .my current requirement is to get a field value from xml based on CSV input value for each row.. how can i do it kindly help..

my CSV file content looks something like this

```
id|key |value
10|000-0|12
```

and xml  file which existis in the same folder looks like

```
   <customer id="10"> 
        <type>frequent buyer</type>
    </customer>
```

now i am getting the Id value(10 in this case) from csv  in a field named ID so how can i get the corresponding type value('frequent buyer') from xml to another field named type in logstash. How can i concurrently parse both csv and xml. since for each row in csv i have to fetch this value from xml. can it be done using XPATH in xml filter

can source attribute point to a real xml path other than message ?

```
xml {
        store_xml => "true"
        source => 
}
```

i am a newbie on logstash. Kindly help.. Thanks for your help in advance.